# Xubuntu 9.10 LiveCD on USB fails with error can't open /dev/sr0: no medium found

Tags: ubuntu, usb, boot, livecd, xubuntu

Using Ubuntu's USB Startup Disk Creator (USB-creator-gtk), I created a LiveUSB from the Xubuntu 9.10 LiveCD. When booting, it stalls up with the Xubuntu mouse splash screen displayed.

In attempting to troubleshoot, I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to check out the first virtual terminal. On that screen, I see over and over again the lines:

```
stdin: I/O error
stdin: error 0
/init: line 1: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the answer elsewhere, so I decided to document my findings on superuser.

If you just wait a really long time, xubuntu will give up trying to access `/dev/sr0`, and then the live-usb image will boot.

There is probably a trickier way to get the problem to stop happening.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be caused by a reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/500822

> As has already been pointed out, **disabling the floppy drive will suppress the message**. A better fix would be for the casper devs to change line 44 of /scripts/casper-helpers from "eval $(fstype < $1)" to "eval $(fstype $1 2>/dev/null)".

Comment: I disabled the floppy controller from BIOS, and it boots up normally.